# Mapping ActiveRecord Objects to create a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oop

I am looking for advice on how to do something I have wanted to do many times in the past, which leads me to believe that there is a design pattern (and likely a gem, or examples) of how to do exactly what I want to achieve.

I am currently working in *Rails* on a project involving many types of orders.  For example, I have a basic order which needs to generate a shipment.  The data in the order needs to be *"mapped"* to a newly created shipment.  (Very brief example:)

> `Order`
>   - from: NYC
>   - to: LA
>   - shipping_type: FedEx
>
> `Shipment`
>   - from: LA
>   - to: NYC
>   - shipping_type: FedEx

The *Order* and *Shipment* will have nearly identical fields, one of the minor differences is that the "*from*" and "*to*" fields switch.  In the real world, each of these objects have many, many more fields.  There are also many other types of orders that need to have "*maps*".

In interest of trying to keep things *DRY*, is there a way to create maps between these orders, so that I can minimize the number of times that I will have to write a `generate_order_from(order)` method?

**Edit:  I am attempting to create a method similar to [RestKit's Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md).  I just can't find anything similar in Ruby.**

Answer (score 0):

> The order and shipment will have nearly identical fields ... In the real world, each of these objects have many, many more fields.

Perhaps this is your problem? If you have so many fields and most of them are identical in the order and the shipment, you should pull the common fields into a separate object that is shared by both the order and the shipment (in the database, this would equate to normalizing your tables). Then you would only have to map the fields that actually change (such as switching the `from` and `to` fields).

Comment: Thanks, casablanca.  I have all of the shared fields pulled into another object called "Order", which is supported by the database.  The requirements for the project require a full auditing, though, which eliminates the ability for the different orders to share the same underlying object, as a purchase order may generate multiple shipments.  I am attempting to create a method similar to [RestKit's Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md).